# Recycling Bitmap in android

Tags: android, bitmap

When one should take care of Bitmap memory management or recycling bitmap in android ?

For example , there are few ways to create a bitmaps in android like following

```
 Bitmap.createBitmap
 Bitmap.createScaledBitmap
 BitmapFactory
```

But when android allocate memory for bitmap which must be cleared so that in future application we won't face running out of memory error problem

Comment: The subject is interesting but please add some punctuation to let us understand what is your question...

Comment: Over-optimization is root of all evil. Optimize when needed and release bitmaps when not in use.

Comment: in the Official Documentation, you can find a Full Example which treat loading large bitmaps effeciently and how to recycle them : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Answer (score 1):

In Android versions prior to 3.0, the Bitmaps are allocated outside of the VM. Android gets back this memory in Bitmap's finalize() method. You can let Android reclaim the memory faster by calling Bitmap.recycle() instead of waiting on the GC to call finalize() on them.

This is only really a problem if you're creating and discarding a lot of the Bitmaps. That is, if you are allocating memory faster then the GC can clean up the garbage left behind, at which point you get an OutOfMemoryError.

In android 3.0 and later, the Bitmap memory is allocated inside of the VM, so Bitmap memory can be reclaimed without having to call finalize() on them.

Answer (score 0):

you recycle the bitmap whenever you don't need it. for example

```
@Override 
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(bitmap !=null){
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap = null;
    } 
}
@Override 
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   if(bitmap !=null){
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap = null;
  } 
}
```

P.S bitmaps memory are acting different from each devices, what i mean is

```
Growing Heap
```

is different from device to another 
for example Bitmap size can exceed VM budget(Growing Heap) up to 240MB on the S4 `tested and confirmed by personal testing` and it doesn't cause `OutOfMemoryError` but in some other devices if the bitmap size exceed (Growing Heap) up to  16MB it may cause `OutOfMemoryError` its quite different from device to another because some devices has large heap while some not. and trust me dealing with Growing Heap is not easy task. 
additional advice is to use `android:largeHeap="true"`   in your `application` tag inside of the manifest.
`

Comment: Set the object to null, and then call recycle on that object?

Comment: it should be the opposite as @Software.Developer said, and for a full example about loading large bitmaps effeciently, take a look at the official documentation  : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html